# White space bellow a a fixed size background

Tags: html, css, background-image, removing-whitespace, responsive-images

I'm making a website and the client wants to use a full screen background image as the layout. I'm trying to make this sort of responsive, by making the background a fixed size and having the user scroll though the page, but I'm having a problem where below it there is white space that I can't get rid of.
[Here is a gif of the problem](https://giphy.com/gifs/lNFHeDPaLcN5XqCUJ3)

And here is the css

```
@media (max-width: 1279px) {
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 1280px;
}

body {
background: url('Imagenes/Render_Nutricia.jpg') no-repeat;
background-size: 1280px 720px;
 }
}
@media (min-width: 1280px) {
body {
 background-image: url("Imagenes/Render_Nutricia.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: background-size:cover; 

cover Resize the background image to cover the entire container, even if it has to stretch the image or cut a little bit off one of the edges
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand why you use media queries for this. Please check the codes below. The property that you're looking for is `background-size: cover;`

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    background: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I need the user to be able to scroll though the image to click the buttons, and with cover doesn't show fully and can't be scrolled, at least I couldn't make it do it.